# filesize output redirect in batch

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, filesize, output-redirect

I'm trying to create a batch file to go through a folder and output all of the file sizes of each file in the specified folder to a .txt

So far I have the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set size=
FOR /R (F:\mediav3) %%A IN (*) DO set size=%%~zA
```

I'm having issues with the actual output. I've tried using echo`%size% > temp.txt` and a few other variations.Based on other output redirects posts I've found here but haven't managed to come up with a working solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what you need *size* variable for? If it only to output to file, then it's not needed, `FOR /R F:\mediav3 %%A IN (*) DO echo %%~zA >> temp.txt` will work

Comment: I'm building a file list for the mediav3 folder via XML so I can reference it in another batch file to remove any files that are not on the list based on file names and sizes.

Comment: if you don't do calculations on size (divide, multiply etc.) you may use for parameters directly without assigning it to variable first. Please note Bali's answer is also correct and it shows you something called *delayed expansion* which is good to be aware of. Also note that `>>` means append, so you need to zero your file first. Let me know if you need more guidance I will make it proper answer in that case.

Comment: Got it working, thanks wmz. Didn't realize you could use the parameters directly.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r F:\mediav3 %%a in (*) do (
set size=%%~za
echo !size! >>C:\sizes.txt
)
```

Comment: Just tried it, the output file sizes.txt gets created but is a blank document. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested my final batch file is the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal
echo ^<fileinfo^>
FOR /R F:\MEDIAV3 %%A IN (*) DO echo ^<filename^>%%~fA^</filename^>>>fileinfo.xml & echo      ^<bytes^>%%~zA^</bytes^>>>fileinfo.xml & echo.>>fileinfo.xml
echo ^</fileinfo^>>>fileinfo.xml
```

The batch output is formatted to easily convert filenames and filesizes into and xml list. There is probably a cleaner way of doing it but this certainly worked.